# Azure DevOps API Create Task under User Story

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I can created a User Story using this endpoint "_apis/wit/workitems"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

but I cannot figure out how to create a task(s) under a User Story using the API.
I did some research for 2 days but I couldn't figure it out.  Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

If you have already your user story than you need to create a task first using the same endpoint. After that you need to update your parent to add relation to your task as it is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-link)

Your body should be like this:

```json
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",//Add a child link
      ##"rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",//Add a parent link
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work item id}"
    }
  }
]
```